# Mac shows desktop without menu bar or Dock after updating Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard

During a system update on my MacBook (Mac OS X 10.6.8) it restarted and during the restart I have got a screen where it looks like the homepage but doesn't have the menu bar at the top or the Dock at the bottom and it would make a noise when I pressed the screen. Apple Support had me verifying stuff on the Disk Utility then it cut off. Can anyone help me? I can't download anything till this is sorted.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what's currently on your screen?

Answer (score 1):

A few of things for you to try...

First, try starting in **Safe Boot** by holding the **Shift** key when you hear the startup chime. If you manage to successfully boot in this way and you can access the internet, download and install [OS X 10.6.8 Combo Update V1.1](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399?locale=en_GB). Restart and see what happens...

If that doesn't work - and you have the original discs that shipped with your Mac - start your Mac from disc 1, **OS X Install Disc**. Once it has started up find **Disk Utility** from the menu bar and select **Repair Disk**. When that has done select **Repair Permissions**. Finally, restart and see what happens...

If you installed from a retail copy of 10.6, follow the same steps above.

If you don't have the original discs, start your Mac and hold **command + S** to boot into single user mode. When it has booted you will see a command prompt, type in `/sbin/fsck –fy`, press the **Enter** key when done. A disk check will then be performed. When that's finished, type `shutdown -r now` at the command prompt. Wait for it to restart and see what happens...

Comment: Hi I am also experiencing the same problem and have followed all your instructions. Unfortunately I'm still experiencing the same problems. Do you think a complete system reinstall is necessary to fix this? Also, if that is the case is there a way to backup data on the same hard-drive before re-installing the OS? Thank you!